# Why upload module in repository not found via pip install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, artifactory

I upload module 
example-framework.python.egg
via Jenkins in JFrog Artifactory.
Upload completed good without errors.

I checked in Artifactory, in repository browser saw in properties
pypi.name - **example-framework**

Tried to install module via artifactory.

```
pip install example-framework
```

pip returned error:

```
Collecting example-framework
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement example-framework (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for example-framework
```

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the user running pip, make sure you have correctly setup your ~/.pip/pip.conf file to point to Artifactory. You can see an example of this in the Set Me Up box for the pipy repo.

Comment: In addition to what Scott suggested, also look at the artifactory.log and reqeust.log of Artifactory and see if there is any error/request listed there.